# How to display html content to the right of other content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a personal website and I have all of the HTML done, it's just that in the CSS when I try to display it next to another section of the HTML I don't know how to do it. (I want to display the Demo's to the right of the introduction without messing up the images.)

I've tried to change the flex-direction to column and other things but I don't know if that is the issue.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Tito's Website!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="MainContent">
      <h1>Im Tito</h1>
      <h2>-A Programmer-</h2>
      <br />
      <p>Hello, my name is Tito Osi. Im intrested in programming</p>
      <br />
      <div>
         <h2>About me:</h2>
         <p>
            I am a middle school student in 7th grade right now. some of my
            intrests include: <br />Computer science, Software enginnering,
            software development, App development, and gamming.
         </p>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />

      <div>
         <h2>Programming Enthusiast.</h2>
         <p>
            I have experience coding in HTML, CSS, Java-script, and python and I
            love software enginnering. <br>I code in CSS to make my projects look my
            beautifull!
         </p>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div>
         <h2>Github projects</h2>
         <p>
            I have make a lot of projects, but some that I am most proud of are:
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/Ti7O/Desktop-Assistant-Prototype-1"
                >Tito's Desktop Assistant</a
                ></li><br />
                <li><a href="https://github.com/Ti7O/Secure-Random-Password-Generator"
                >Tito's Secure Random Passowrd Generator</a
                ></li><br />
                <li><a href="https://github.com/Ti7O/Currency-Converter"
                >Tito's Currency Converter</a
                ></li><br />
                <li><a href="https://github.com/Ti7O/Calculator"
                >Tito's Simple Calculator</a
                ></li><br />
            </ul>
         </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProjectDemos">
        <h1>Demos!:</h1>
        <button class="Button">Desktop Assistant <img src="bot.png" alt="Robot"></button>
        <button class="Button">Secure Random Password Generator <img src="padlock.png" alt="lock"></button>
        <button class="Button">Currency Converter <img src="currencies.png" alt="currencies"></button>
        <button class="Button">Calculator <img src="calculator.png" alt="calculator"></button>
    </div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   font-family: Verdana;
}

.MainContent {
   border: 5px solid #000; /* Sets a black border around the content */
   padding: 10px; /* Adds some space inside the border */
   margin: 20px; /* Adds some space outside the border */
   border-radius: 20px;
   width: 1000px;
}

.ProjectDemos {
   border: 5px solid #000; /* Sets a black border around the content */
   padding: 10px; /* Adds some space inside the border */
   margin: 20px; /* Adds some space outside the border */
   border-radius: 20px;
   width: 500px;
}

.Button {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column; /* Align items vertically */
   align-items: center; /* Center items horizontally */
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 20px;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   border-radius: 20px;
}

.Button img {
   max-width: 90%; /* Ensure the image doesn't exceed the button width */
}
```

Comment: If you give a `<div>` the style `float: right`, that div will be shoved to the right margin and the other material will flow down around it.

Comment: I did that change now, but I want it to align together side by side

Comment: Well, then, make them both `float: left`.  The second will be placed to the immediate right of the first.

Comment: In my experience it helps to read documentation and tutorials to understand the concepts of HTML/CSS. Combining them will then be easier. For example: [MDN docs: CSS layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout)

Comment: You can either use grid-system of flex-box as well

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the flexbox method.
Create a parent element that contains both of these child elements and set `display: flex` on the parent `.flex-container` element.

```css
body {
   font-family: Verdana;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.MainContent {
   border: 5px solid #000; /* Sets a black border around the content */
   padding: 10px; /* Adds some space inside the border */
   margin: 20px; /* Adds some space outside the border */
   border-radius: 20px;
   width: 1000px;
}

.ProjectDemos {
   border: 5px solid #000; /* Sets a black border around the content */
   padding: 10px; /* Adds some space inside the border */
   margin: 20px; /* Adds some space outside the border */
   border-radius: 20px;
   width: 500px;
}

.Button {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column; /* Align items vertically */
   align-items: center; /* Center items horizontally */
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 20px;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   border-radius: 20px;
}

.Button img {
   max-width: 90%; /* Ensure the image doesn't exceed the button width */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Tito's Website!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="MainContent">
          <h1>Im Tito</h1>
          <h2>-A Programmer-</h2>
          <br />
          <p>Hello, my name is Tito Osi. Im intrested in programming</p>
          <br />
          <div>
             <h2>About me:</h2>
             <p>
                I am a middle school student in 7th grade right now. some of my
                intrests include: <br />Computer science, Software enginnering,
                software development, App development, and gamming.
             </p>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />

          <div>
             <h2>Programming Enthusiast.</h2>
             <p>
                I have experience coding in HTML, CSS, Java-script, and python and I
                love software enginnering. <br>I code in CSS to make my projects look my
                beautifull!
             </p>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <div>
             <h2>Github projects</h2>
             <p>
                I have make a lot of projects, but some that I am most proud of are:
             </p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://github.com/Ti7O/Desktop-Assistant-Prototype-1"
                    >Tito's Desktop Assistant</a
                    ></li><br />
                    <li><a href="https://github.com/Ti7O/Secure-Random-Password-Generator"
                    >Tito's Secure Random Passowrd Generator</a
                    ></li><br />
                    <li><a href="https://github.com/Ti7O/Currency-Converter"
                    >Tito's Currency Converter</a
                    ></li><br />
                    <li><a href="https://github.com/Ti7O/Calculator"
                    >Tito's Simple Calculator</a
                    ></li><br />
                </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ProjectDemos">
            <h1>Demos!:</h1>
            <button class="Button">Desktop Assistant <img src="bot.png" alt="Robot"></button>
            <button class="Button">Secure Random Password Generator <img src="padlock.png" alt="lock"></button>
            <button class="Button">Currency Converter <img src="currencies.png" alt="currencies"></button>
            <button class="Button">Calculator <img src="calculator.png" alt="calculator"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```